# OracleDb for Node.js searching date with like and wildcard seems not to work while in oracle application client it does

Tags: sql, node.js, oracle, date, node-oracledb

i'm using oracleDB for NodeJS, i dont know why query having the

```
LIKE '%/12'
```

not working on **Date types** and returns always empty array likewise it's still returning results for the same query inside Oracle client interface.

I tried escaping the '\', bypass binding thought it just interpreted it as params that should be passed.

Comment: What do you expect `LIKE '%/12'` to match? Is `12` meant to be the year, month, day or seconds?

Comment: Can you provide an example? What data are you running through that LIKE statement? What is the expected result? etc.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @MT0 yeah you're right i didn't paid attention to date since it was working on Oracle Client Interface that i didn't blame the query it self, the match for the year.

Comment: @DavidKidwell they kind like wanted to list last inserted folder at a specific year, the %/12 meaning 2012 which they told me that the field having only 2 position where month having 2 position and year having 2 two as-well, ex: 2012 => 12, at the end of day i tried %/%/%12 it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle, a `DATE` is a binary data-type consisting of 7 bytes representing century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second. It **ALWAYS** has those 7 components and it is **NEVER** stored in any particular human-readable format.

When you use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  date_column LIKE '%/12'
```

You are implicitly converting the date to a string so you are effectively doing:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  TO_CHAR(
         date_column,
         (SELECT value FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT')
       ) LIKE '%/12'
```

If your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` does not match (i.e. it has a `-` instead of `/` or the format is `DD/MM/YYYY` so that there is a 4-digit year at the end) then you will never match using `LIKE`. Similarly, if your client application sets a specific `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` for your session but the NodeJS connection uses a different default for the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` then you will get different behaviour when you rely on implicit conversions.

Either explicitly convert your date to a string:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  TO_CHAR(date_column, 'MM') = '12'
```

Or:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  TO_CHAR(date_column, 'YYYY/MM/DD') LIKE '%/12'
```

*But using `LIKE` seems pointless when you could just compare a single component of the date.*

Or use `EXTRACT`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  EXTRACT(DAY FROM date_column) = 12
```

Or, if you are expecting `12` to match a 2-digit year then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  date_column >= DATE '2012-01-01'
AND    date_column <  DATE '2013-01-01'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer and your time, the thing is, I was so focused and wondering why in client works and not the case for NodeJS that I didn't release it was kind of illogic to check the value "/%12" with 2 parts which lead to confusion, they just gave me that query and i thought it was only month and year, then i tried this %/%/%24 to get the desired result.

i tried to get the OCI configuration settings but i figured out that the NodeJS library was not built as OCI one hopping that it ll behave same as the OCI.

TYSM.